# Rake db:migrate error Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dbmigrate

Briefing: I've been attempting to deploy my blog to heroku for the last week with no luck. I've contacted Heroku support and they've pretty much told me to post the log on stackoverflow. So here I am.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with postgreSQL but I may be wrong. Anyway here's the codebase: www.github.com/apane/blogit_blog.

Heroku log below.

Gemfile provided for good measure:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'blogit', '0.8.0'

gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4"

gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'  
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Rake db:migrate error log:

```
    rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/anthonypanepinto/Sites/personal_blog/personal_blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I ran into this just last week. My problem was in the Gemfile - there was a reference to "sqlite3" that had to be commented out. I don't see it in yours and your pg gem appears correct - did you bundle before deployment? Also, check your database.yml, which is pre-set to use sqlite3 as the adapter. Sqlite3 must be commented out and postgresql added instead. (Hope this isn't too basic, I'm a beginner myself.)

Comment: 3 answers with no votes or comments. Did anything here help you? I am having a similar problem (same error, but not with Heroku)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using sqlite in development.

Can you try this in your gemfile instead of what you have?

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end
```

Then usual bundle install and run migration again.

Comment: I am getting the same error but already have my Gemfile structured this way with sqlite3 in the dev/test group

Answer (score 0):

The error `Please install the sqlite3 adapter: 'gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter'` is indicative of your local environment being configured to run SQLite, but SQLite isn't installed. The message references the `activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` gem, but within your Gemfile, within a fully integrated Rails environment, you'll only need to bundle the `sqlite3` for the environment you want to run (presumably development & test, since your production is on Heroku, which uses Postgres).

Replace your `group :development, test` block in your Gemfile with the following:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Heroku uses the config property DATABASE_URL instead of your database.yml file for connecting to your db. Make sure it is set.

heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=sqlite3://bb06ca765fb123:71b6dabc@us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com/heroku_703eded6aebc123?reconnect=true